# Manually create a react element Object with streaming

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to create a react element object manually without using react.createElement.

The idea is to create nested react elements tree while streaming from html. The problem is I am unaware of nested children during streaming.

My objective is to be able to create a react element from a nested object. ie:

```
{
   "tag": "div",
   "attribs": {},
   "children": [
      {
         "tag": "p",
         "attribs": {},
         "children": [],
         "text": "test"
      },
      {
         "tag": "div",
         "attribs": {},
         "children": [
            {
               "tag": "p",
               "attribs": {},
               "children": [],
               "text": "hi"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You'll have to make a component that handles that json passed into it and makes new elements.

Answer (score -2):

You can also create nested components by using `React.createElement`, but you need to follow a special syntax to achieve that.

`tag` needs to be `type` and `attribs` need to be `props`, but you may iterate over your object and rename those keys if needed, so that's not the problem.

Now having something like this:

```
var data = {
   "type": "div",
   "props": {anyProp: true},
   "children": [
      {
         "type": "p",
         "props": {},
         "children": [],
         "text": "test"
      },
      {
         "type": "div",
         "props": {},
         "children": [
            {
               "type": "p",
               "props": {},
               "children": [],
               "text": "hi"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

You can just use `React.createElement(data.type, data.props, data.children);` to create a component including all **children, properties** et cetera.

Comment: The question specifically asks if it is possible to create a react element object manually **without** using react.createElement

Comment: As @zackify already said above I think this can't be achieved as simple as that. Why exactly can't you use `createElement` in your case?

Comment: The idea was to create nested react elements while streaming from html.